# Axial and vector resonances in composite Higgs models

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gauge-theory, higgs

Is there a reason to believe that the axial resonances are heavier than the vector resonances in the composite Higgs models?

For instance, in [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2071), to have zero tree level contributions to S parameter, the constraint on the wave function mixing parameter $\epsilon$, makes axial resonances lighter. However, models constructed with CCWZ formalism, seem to favor heavier axial resonances as compared to the $\rho$'s.